# Do I deserve downvotes for answering such a simple question?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, vote-to-close

In other words, should such a simple question be answered or closed (and answering deserves downvotes):

[Are nested queries standard in the SQL language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9442895/are-nested-queries-standard-in-the-sql-language/9443212#9443212)

Perhaps the title of this question is not appropriate. What I meant was that after answering, I felt like I should be downvoted.

A question that can simply be answered by a Google search (searching "SQL standard" gives all the info one wants), should be deleted or answered?

Comment: You didn't receive any downvotes for your answer there. What are you asking?

Comment: @CodyGray: You beat me to it. I had the same question.

Comment: @Cody and Martin: See my edit.

Comment: No, but you did receive several upvotes after posting this question.  *Well played, sir.*  ;-P

Comment: @AdamDavis: It really works. *Have no idea before how well it works :)*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Completely trivial questions that can easily be Googled are a problem. They should not be answered, but downvoted and closed instead.

However, the question you show, while simple, isn't *entirely* trivial, it demonstrates an interest in something deeper, and it feels like your answer adds value to the site. I don't think there is a problem with it.

Comment: Value is relative. A noob will find simple questions and answer of value, till their knowledge increases.

Comment: @108.im to me, trivial questions are best answered by the respective documentation. Answering them on Stack Overflow as well is superfluous and creates duplication, which over time leads to outdated information. There is a limit to how simple a SO question should be in order to be useful.

Comment: I agree that the *questions* are problematic, and should be downvoted/closed. But I don't think that applies to the *answers* to those questions, which is what this question appears to be talking about. They should be judged on their own merit. If they're uniquely helpful, upvote them. If they're *wrong* or particularly unhelpful, downvote them. Generally, I'd refrain from voting on them at all.

Answer (score 8):

No, you don't. Your answer is pretty nice, I think, so I don't think you would deserve to be downvoted.

However, it's everyone's opinion an choice whether to downvote you or not.

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/179123/1044146) question. It's pretty simple but highly upvoted, because it's original, unique.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think that answers to simple questions should be automatically down-voted, which means the fact somebody answers a simple question is not a reason for down-voting the answer.

There are users who write great answers for questions that are simple, and I don't think such answers should be down-voted. Clearly, if the answer is simply "Yes." or something along those lines, the answer is not helpful, but that is true independently from how much easy the question is.